# Could I save multiple files with same name?

Tags: file, directory

I just wonder whether I can save multiple files with the same name.

Is it okay to make and save multiple 'index.html' files if I save them to the different folders each?

I'm afraid the new one might overwrite the old one.

Comment: You should specify what OS, preferably filesystem, you're talking about.. But I've never heard of one that has directories and doesn't allow the same file name in multiple directories.

Comment: Please, try to describe your problem more detailed next time. 
The best way is to do it, is to provide some real sample of your problem.

Comment: Thank you guys! I will write more details next time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is ok. You can have one index.html and or one index.html in every directory inside your webserver data folder, or any other folder you want to store your files.

You just cannot have two identically named files in the same directory. The most common used file systems does not allow it.